# Is there a TeX/LaTeX maths workbook like Sympy live shell?

Tags: sagetex

I am looking for a mathematics workbook like [Sympy live shell](http://live.sympy.org/) that you can do plots in, that has a TeX or LaTeX output.

Comment: Hi, welcome. What exactly do you mean by "LaTeX output"?

Comment: the best example I can give is this: http://live.sympy.org/ The sympy live shell will calculate a python input and produce the output rendered in LaTex. Sage math can output raw LaTex, I was curious if there was a way to make it output rendered LaTex.

Comment: Now I'm just more confused. By "raw LaTeX", do you mean code? And the output from Sage you're talking about; output of what, exactly? You were talking about plots, do you mean just any plot that can be used in LaTeX (which could just be a `.pdf` file, or `.png` file), or do you want code using e.g. the `pgfplots` or `pstricks` package that will render to a plot?

Comment: by "raw LaTeX" I mean code, for example: f(x) = x^2
latex( f) would produce: x \ {\mapsto}\ x^{2}. by plots I mean for example the plot of $x^{2}$ and its derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with the [Sage Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) and Python, just use that. You'll have access to all the goodies of `sympy`, and you can save the plots  as for example PDF files, that can be used in a LaTeX document with `\includegraphics`.

For example if you have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,2))
ax.plot(np.random.rand(20))
fig.savefig('test.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
```

in a Sage worksheet and run that, you will get `test.pdf` in the project folder, that can then be downloaded, and used in a LaTeX file as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{test}
\end{document}
```